# How to sort a NumPy array of strings by the last column

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Is there a way to sort the rows of an array by the last element, in this case the cell ids. The cell id is build as follows : "CellID_NumberOfCell

```
arr =np.array([['65.0','30.0','20.0','0.0','0_0'],
 ['2.0','29.0','24.0','0.0','1_0'],
 ['0.0','18.0','4.0','0.0','2_0'],
 ['16.0','9.0','0.0','9990.0','7_203'],
 ['16.0','9.0','0.0','9990.0','0_203'],
 ['20.0','23.0','31.0','9990.0','8_158'],
 ['65.0','30.0','20.0','0.0','0_10']])
```

So after sorting it should look like:

```
arr =np.array([['65.0','30.0','20.0','0.0','0_0'],
 ['65.0','30.0','20.0','0.0','0_10'],
 ['16.0','9.0','0.0','9990.0','0_203'],
 ['2.0','29.0','24.0','0.0','1_0'],
 ['0.0','18.0','4.0','0.0','2_0'],
 ['16.0','9.0','0.0','9990.0','7_203'],
 ['20.0','23.0','31.0','9990.0','8_158']])
```

**EDIT:**

Is it also possible to delete the numbers after the underscore after sorting?. So that i just have the ID. Instead of 0_0 just 0.

**EDIT2**

After sorting the ID, it should also sort after time, so that every ID with 0 for example should also be sorted after time 0,1...9999 etc.

Comment: Edit the question title to reflect it's intention; something like, "How to sort a NumPy array by the last element of each row?"

Comment: How can I check which answer has the best runtime? :)

Comment: @Varlor Use an input with : `arr[np.random.randint(0,arr.shape[0],(1000))]` to test out all approaches? You may vary that `1000` there.

Comment: @Divakar Hey, how does this function work? Does it analyze the structure of my input and generates 1000 randomes in the shape of it?

Comment: @Varlor Basically gets those rows off `arr` in random order with repeats and gets us a `(1000,5)` shaped array.

Comment: @Divakar ah ok, thanks!!

Comment: @Varlor Added one version of timings test in my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to split the last column by that `underscore`, lexsort it and then use those indices to sort the input array.

Thus, an implementation would be -

```
def numpy_app(arr):
    # Extract out the strings on last column split based on '_'.
    # Thus, for given sample we would have the last column would be
    # split further into 3 columns, the middle one being of '_''s.
    a = np.core.defchararray.partition(arr[:,-1],'_')

    # Lexsort it on the last numeric cols (0,2). We need to flip
    # the order of columns to give precedence to the first string
    sidx = np.lexsort(a[:,2::-2].astype(int).T)

    # Index into input array with lex-sorted indices for final o/p
    return arr[sidx]
```

Based on the edits in the question, it seems we want to cut out the string after the underscore. To do so, here's a modified version -

```
def numpy_cut_app(arr):
    a = np.core.defchararray.partition(arr[:,-1],'_')
    sidx = np.lexsort(a[:,2::-2].astype(int).T)
    out = arr[sidx]

    # Replace the last column with the first string off the last column's split one
    out[:,-1] = a[sidx,0]
    return out
```

Based on more edits, it seems we want to include the fourth column into lex-sorting and neglect everything after the underscore in the last column. So, a further modified version would be -

```
def numpy_cut_col3_app(arr):
    a = np.core.defchararray.partition(arr[:,-1],'_')

    # Lex-sort using first off the split strings from last col(precedence to it)
    # and col-3 of input array
    sidx = np.lexsort([arr[:,3].astype(float), a[:,0]])
    out = arr[sidx]
    out[:,-1] = a[sidx,0]
    return out
```

Sample runs -

```
In [567]: arr
Out[567]: 
array([['65.0', '30.0', '20.0', '0.0', '9_49'],
       ['2.0', '29.0', '24.0', '0.0', '1_0'],
       ['0.0', '18.0', '4.0', '0.0', '2_0'],
       ['16.0', '9.0', '0.0', '9990.0', '7_203'],
       ['16.0', '9.0', '0.0', '9990.0', '9_5'],
       ['20.0', '23.0', '31.0', '9990.0', '8_158'],
       ['65.0', '30.0', '20.0', '0.0', '9_50']], 
      dtype='|S6')

In [568]: numpy_app(arr)
Out[568]: 
array([['2.0', '29.0', '24.0', '0.0', '1_0'],
       ['0.0', '18.0', '4.0', '0.0', '2_0'],
       ['16.0', '9.0', '0.0', '9990.0', '7_203'],
       ['20.0', '23.0', '31.0', '9990.0', '8_158'],
       ['16.0', '9.0', '0.0', '9990.0', '9_5'],
       ['65.0', '30.0', '20.0', '0.0', '9_49'],
       ['65.0', '30.0', '20.0', '0.0', '9_50']], 
      dtype='|S6')

In [569]: numpy_cut_app(arr)
Out[569]: 
array([['2.0', '29.0', '24.0', '0.0', '1'],
       ['0.0', '18.0', '4.0', '0.0', '2'],
       ['16.0', '9.0', '0.0', '9990.0', '7'],
       ['20.0', '23.0', '31.0', '9990.0', '8'],
       ['16.0', '9.0', '0.0', '9990.0', '9'],
       ['65.0', '30.0', '20.0', '0.0', '9'],
       ['65.0', '30.0', '20.0', '0.0', '9']], 
      dtype='|S6')
```

Comment: Nice! The problem here now is sth like here:
['10.0' '33.0' '14.0' '2505.0' '9_49']
['1.0' '12.0' '15.0' '180.0' '9_5']
['12.0' '3.0' '15.0' '2520.0' '9_50']. 5 is sorted between 49 and 50.

Comment: I added an edit. Is it also possible to do that after sorting?

Comment: @Varlor Updated. Fixed that `5`, `49`, `50` sorting issue.

Comment: Ok thank you very much!!! Unfortunately i made a mistake in my question. It should be sorted by the ID like you did it, but also after the time(column 3). So the output of your test should be: array([['2.0', '29.0', '24.0', '0.0', '1'],
       ['0.0', '18.0', '4.0', '0.0', '2'],
       ['16.0', '9.0', '0.0', '9990.0', '7'],
       ['20.0', '23.0', '31.0', '9990.0', '8'],
       ['65.0', '30.0', '20.0', '0.0', '9'],
       ['65.0', '30.0', '20.0', '0.0', '9']],
       ['16.0', '9.0', '0.0', '9990.0', '9'],
      dtype='|S6')

Comment: @Varlor By third col, do you mean `arr[:,3]` or `arr[:,2]`?

Comment: I mean arr[:,3] :)

Comment: Check out just added `numpy_cut_col3_app`.

Comment: It works, but now the numbers after the underscore are not cut :(

Comment: @Varlor Ah yes! Just fixed it.

Comment: it works perfect! Can you explain your function? I also would to know how I can use the timeit function :) best regards!

Comment: @Varlor Edited. To use timing, google for `timing with timeit`.

Answer (score 5):

`np.argsort(arr[:, -1])` will give you the permutation so that elements of the last column of `arr` are ordered.

Then, `arr[np.argsort(arr[:, -1])]` reorders the rows of arr according to this permutation.

Beware that the lexicographic order is used since your data consists of string, so `0_10` comes before `0_2`. If this is not what you want, you should split the last column, and I advise you to use a `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
df['Cell'], df['CellIndex'] = df[df.columns[-1]].str.split('_', 1).str
df['Cell'] = df['Cell'].astype(int)
df['CellIndex'] = df['CellIndex'].astype(int)
df.sort_values(['Cell', 'CellIndex'])
```

pandas is really the way to go to manipulate this kind of data.

Comment: Is arr really a numpy array ? What is type(arr) ? Try arr = np.array(arr)

Comment: yeah, was a mistake of me. But the next problem is that the output now is pandas data frame. is it possible to cast it back to numpy array? :)

Comment: I added an edit. Is it also possible to do that after sorting?

Comment: @Varlor arr = np.array(df). Pandas relies heavily on numpy :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easely with sorted and lambda function and as suggested by @Divakar to get the numpy array back:

```
np.array(sorted(arr, key=lambda x :x[-1]))
```

output

```
[['65.0', '30.0', '20.0', '0.0', '0_0'],
['65.0', '30.0', '20.0', '0.0', '0_10'],
['16.0', '9.0', '0.0', '9990.0', '0_203'],
['2.0', '29.0', '24.0', '0.0', '1_0'],
['0.0', '18.0', '4.0', '0.0', '2_0'],
['16.0', '9.0', '0.0', '9990.0', '7_203'],
['20.0', '23.0', '31.0', '9990.0', '8_158']]
```

EDIT : 
 you can do it by using this, not pretty, but does the work

```
np.array([ np.append(i[:-1],i[-1].split("_")[0]) for i in sorted(list(arr), key=lambda x :x[-1])])
```

ouput

```
array([['65.0', '30.0', '20.0', '0.0', '0'],
       ['65.0', '30.0', '20.0', '0.0', '0'],
       ['16.0', '9.0', '0.0', '9990.0', '0'],
       ['2.0', '29.0', '24.0', '0.0', '1'],
       ['0.0', '18.0', '4.0', '0.0', '2'],
       ['16.0', '9.0', '0.0', '9990.0', '7'],
       ['20.0', '23.0', '31.0', '9990.0', '8']], 
      dtype='<U6')
```

Comment: If i use your approach i got something like this (arrays in array):

[array(['65.0', '30.0', '20.0', '0.0', '0_0'], 
      dtype='|S6'), array(['65.0', '30.0', '20.0', '0.0', '0_10'], 
      dtype='|S6'), array(['16.0', '9.0', '0.0', '9990.0', '0_203'], 
      dtype='|S6'), array(['2.0', '29.0', '24.0', '0.0', '1_0'], 
      dtype='|S6'), array(['0.0', '18.0', '4.0', '0.0', '2_0'], 
      dtype='|S6'), array(['16.0', '9.0', '0.0', '9990.0', '7_203'], 
      dtype='|S6'), array(['20.0', '23.0', '31.0', '9990.0', '8_158'], 
      dtype='|S6')]

Comment: @valor wasn't that the original format ? If not can you provide a way for people to reproduce your data ? if i enter your line arr =..., i get TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str, so i assumed it was a nested list

Comment: @Varlor Use `np.array()` to get back an array output.

Comment: I added an edit. Is it also possible to do that after sorting?

Comment: @Varlor Good. : ) If everything is working, can you accept one of the asnwer that fit best your need ?